# What does "teeth-rattling heap" mean?

Tags: meaning, expressions

It's from the **IT** novel by Stephen King. Here's the context:

> Chris Unwin pushed him backward and Hagarty landed in a **teeth-rattling
> heap** on the sidewalk.

What does it mean **to land in a teeth-rattling heap?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Hagarty was pushed over backwards, the fall was awkward and uncontrolled, leading to an ungainly posture on the ground. The force and shock of the fall made Hagarty's jaw open and close, with the teeth knocking against each other, causing a rattling sound.

The ***teeth-rattling heap*** condenses this into a short expressive phrase.

Comment: This is, though, a brilliant, original, metaphor unique to Steven King. It isn't a standard English idiom. Don't expect to see it anywhere else. It's unlikely that King used it again.

Comment: @WeatherVane Wow! That's pretty impressive! I would never guess the meaning myself. So, the word **heap** here means the ungainly posture of Hagarty on the ground, right?

Comment: Yes. _Fell in a heap_ is pretty standard, it's just the bit about the teeth that is unusual.

Comment: **pushed him backward** - Does it mean that Hagarty had his back turned on Chris, so Chris pushed him in the back?

Comment: @JConstantine no, it means that Hagarty was facing Chris, Chris pushed him in the front and Hagarty fell backwards, that is away from Chris in the direction his own back was facing. If I step backwards I move my feet heel first, if l drive my car backwards I have selected reverse gear.

Comment: @BoldBen I've also stumbled upon [this](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Backwards%20Push) and now I'm even more confused. What is the difference between frontal and backwards push then if in both cases the push is made in the front and the one who's been pushed is falling backwards?

Comment: I don't quite follow the description in the Urban Dictionary (or know what a 'normal push' is) but that seems to describe a 'backwards push' street move, not 'push backwards'. Perhaps it means that if you can push someone while facing in the opposite direction (have your back to them), that is what it makes it a humiliating experience for the victim.

Comment: ... back to King's description: if you are falling over 'back first' it's very hard to break your fall and land in a controlled way, and without hitting your head on the ground. Imagine being Hagarty. Unwin steps towards you and gives you an unexpected shove in the chest, which pushes you off balance, and you can't recover. Down you go, probably with your arms windmilling in an attempt to get control of your fall. you hit the ground hard, your jaw goes slack, and your upper and lower teeth bounce against each other.

Comment: This is really not very complicated. Each of the words can be understood independently from its dictionary definition. I myself would interpret “teeth-rattling” more generally as badly shaken up, that is, metaphorically, but that’s not essential.